# I want to put rotate after translate but the rotate effect does not work(CSS 3 aniamtion)

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to create a effect where the a span tag can move up and the spin 1440deg and then move down. However, when I apply the three animations, the rotation effect always resets the position of the span tag(moves back to the origin and then spin instead of spinning at the new position). I have used forwards property but it does not work.

> #audio-text:hover{
>               animation:move-up 0.5s ease-in forwards,spin 1s ease-in 0.5s forwards,move-down 1s ease-in 2s forwards;
>           }
>
> ```
>     @keyframes move-up {
>         0% {
>             transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
>         }
>         100% {
>             transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
>         }
>     }
>
>     @keyframes spin{
>         0%{
>             transform:rotateY(0deg);
>         }
>         100%{
>             transform:rotateY(720deg);
>         }
>     }
>     @keyframes move-down{
>         0%{
>             transform: translate3d(0,-25px,0);
>         }
>         100%{
>             transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for one single animation:

```
  #audio-text:hover{
     animation:upDown 3s 1;
  }


@keyframes upDown
{
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);top:0px;}
  25% {transform: rotate(0deg);top:-25px;}
  50% {transform: rotate(1440deg); top:-25px;}
  75{transform: rotate(1440deg); top:-25px; }
  100% {transform:rotate(1440deg); top:0px; }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it seems like the rotation overwrites the translation .

Comment: In my code there is no translation, actually, the overwriting stuff is the problem in your code, you are using the same propery for different animations on the same element ... a sample here: http://codepen.io/sergio0983/pen/qazogj